# java.lang.VerifyError - android app is not starting after moving development to another machine

Tags: java, android, adb, forceclose

I have been developing an app for weeks on a desktop computer. I have moved to develop on a different machine , so , I checked out the code = built it, all fine - install it via pressing play in eclipse and it fails with a force close.

Not great.

So - This is the stack trace : http://pastebin.com/tUBAK1Zq

I think this is to do with versions of the android sdk possibly - but the version I am running with is the same as on the desktop.

The line the app eventually throws that stack trace on is :

```
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("replaylist").setIndicator("Replay List",
    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tabview_changeicon))
    .setContent(intent);

tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Can somebody please help me get this problem fixed!

Comment: can't access pastebin, can you put stacktrace here?

Comment: http://tinypaste.com/e0452977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the end was due to an out of date android sdk manager i believe

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the "Verify" issue many times myself in Android.  Typically this happens when you use an a standard Java 6 api but the API doesn't exist in Android.  Because your eclipse is "validating" the code based on your JRE then it won't complain if you use an API that doesn't exist in the native Android JRE (dalvik).  And the result is a force close and a cryptic verify message.  You see the alot when you compile a library using a standard java jdk and then use that library in an Android project.

You best bet is to compile your library project using Java 5 compatibility and see which APIs eclipse is complaining about.  Usually you'll find that you are using a Method in String or StringBuffer (or some other core Class) that has not been implemented in Android.  I've also been bitten by using a Constructor that was not implemented in Android.

Comment: Tried this - all it complained about was @Override annotations and inline classes....as i said - this works 100% on my other machine, no code changes have occurred, so why would it suddenly present this error and be associated with an invalid API ? I dont think this is the same problem?

Comment: What intrigues me is the way it is complaining about TabHost.addSpec every time...?

Comment: If you have the source code for your jar, then you can try making the project an Android Library project and use it as such.  In that way, to see if makes a difference, since when using a Library Project the JAR will rebuilt using the dalvik compiler.  The stack trace shows that your activity can't be created, so if your activity is one of your tabs, then that could be why the addTab shows as failing.

Comment: Another thing to check... Make sure that your Android SDK matches that of the Emulator of Device on which you are testing.  ie, if you include the 4.0.3 SDK but then test on a 2.3 device you MAY run into issues if you've used a 4.x api.  (same is true for any 2 version of the SDK -- ie, use a 2.2 api but deploy to 2.1 device)